# Cannot get xml data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, get

I'm trying to get XML data from server, the XML format looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="httpd://www.w3.org/org/2003/05/spap-envlop" env:encodingStyle="httpd:
//www.w3.org/org/2003/05/spap-envlop">
    <env:Body>
        <ip>0.0.0.0</ip>
        <domain>Website</domain>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And I can see all the XML data from Google chrome console with `$.get` method:

```
$(function() {
    $.get("../setup/web.xml", function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
});
```

In the Google chrome console message, it shows "#document" and a small arrow sign tells me that's a fold up message, then I click the arrow sign, my XML data showed up. But I still can't figure out why can't I get XML tag's text from my code below:

```
$(function() {
    $.get("../setup/web.xml", function (data) {
        $("#ip").text(data.ip) //undefined
        $("#domain").text(data.domain) //undefined
    });
});
```

Or even this one:

```
$(function() {
    $.get("../setup/web.xml", function (data) {
        $(data).find("env:Body").each(function () {
            $("#ip").text(ip) //undefined
            $("#domain").text(domain) //undefined
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the way you're accessing the returned data. You're using dot notation which is the method used for accessing an object. You're returning XML, so you'll need to traverse the nodes to find the values you require. Also note that you'll need to escape the `:` in the node name otherwise jQuery will interpret this as a psuedo selector. Try this:

```js
// imagine this is the response text from the request
var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="httpd://www.w3.org/org/2003/05/spap-envlop" env:encodingStyle="httpd://www.w3.org/org/2003/05/spap-envlop"><env:Body><ip>0.0.0.0</ip><domain>Website</domain></env:Body></env:Envelope>';

// this would be inside the callback function of your AJAX request:
var $xml = $(data);
$xml.find('env\\:Body').each(function() {
  var ip = $(this).find('ip').text();
  var domain = $(this).find('domain').text();

  $("#ip").append(ip);
  $("#domain").append(domain);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="domain"></div>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! I'm wondering if the XML data is really really big, and have lots of tags and data in it. What should I do in the first step "var data"?

Comment: You wouldn't need that in your actual code - that's just for the sake of this example as I cannot recreate your AJAX request. You only need the part from `var xml = ...` to the end